# read.zoo works but then as.xts fails with "currently unsupported data type"

Tags: r, xts

I've a csv file of daily bars, with just two lines:

```
"datestamp","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
"2012-07-02",79.862,79.9795,79.313,79.509,48455
```

(That file was an xts that was converted to a data.frame then passed on to `write.csv`)

I load it with this:

```
z=read.zoo(file='tmp.csv',sep=',',header=T,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

And it is fine as `print(z)` shows:

```
           Open   High    Low    Close  Volume
2012-07-02 79.862 79.9795 79.313 79.509 48455
```

But then `as.xts(z)` gives: *Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type*

Here is the `str(z)` output:

```
‘zoo’ series from 2012-07-02 to 2012-07-02
  Data:List of 5
 $ : num 79.9
 $ : num 80
 $ : num 79.3
 $ : num 79.5
 $ : int 48455
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 1 5
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close" ...
  Index:  Date[1:1], format: "2012-07-02"
```

I've so far confirmed it is not that 4 columns are `num` and one column is `int`, as I still get the error even after removing the Volume column. But, then, what could that error message be talking about?

Comment: If you try `getS3method("as.xts", "zoo")`, you can see that the problem you're having is in the line: `xts(coredata(x), order.by = index(x), frequency = NULL)`
Given that `xts` is time series object, is the problem perhaps your single observation?

Comment: @sebastian-c I guess so, because if I duplicate the line in tmp.csv then loading works... so my real question must be how to load a one-record csv file into an xts object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sebastian pointed out in the comments, the problem is in the single row. Specifically the coredata is a list when read.zoo reads a single row, but something else (a matrix?) when there are 2+ rows.

I replaced the call to read.zoo with the following, and it works fine whether 1 or 2+ rows:

```
d=read.table(fname,sep=',',header=T)
x=as.xts(subset(d,select=-datestamp),order.by=as.Date(d$datestamp))
```

Comment: This may be a bug.  The coredata of a xts/zoo object should always be a matrix.